# Group products by category on single product page for grouped product types

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, grouping, product

I have a parent product many grouped products assigned to them (50+). Each grouped product with their own category. Is it possible to group the products by category on the single product page.

Eg:

- Product

  - Category 1

    - Product 1
    - Product 2
    - Product 3
  - Category 2

    - Product 1
    - Product 2
    - Product 3

If it's possible to do this which template should i be editing? The archive product or via custom function.

I've researched SO and many google searches but the majority of results only tell you how to group the products

Comment: Have you tried to edit `single-product/add-to-cart/grouped.php` template?

Comment: that has definately put me on the right track. thank you!